# How to include the .so of custom ops in the pip wheel and organize the sources of custom ops?

Tags: tensorflow

Following [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/adding_an_op/), I put `my_op.cc` and `my_op.cu.cc` under `tensorflow/core/user_ops`, and created `tensorflow/core/user_ops/BUILD` which contains

```
load("//tensorflow:tensorflow.bzl", "tf_custom_op_library")

tf_custom_op_library(
    name = "my_op.so",
    srcs = ["my_op.cc"],
    gpu_srcs = ["my_op.cu.cc"],
)
```

Then I run the following commands under the root of tensorflow:

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/core/user_ops:all
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
```

After building and installing the pip wheel, I want to use `my_op` in the project *`my_project`*.

I think I should create something like `my_project/tf_op/__init__.py` and `my_project/tf_op/my_op.py`, which calls `tf.load_op_library` like [the example cuda_op.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/adding_an_op/cuda_op.py). However, the `my_op.so` is not included in the installed pip wheel. How can I generate the input (the path of `my_op.so`) for `tf.load_op_library`?

Is there any better way to organized `my_op.cc`, `my_op.cu.cc`, `my_op.py` with *`my_project`*?

Comment: It's a bit clunky. Our current solution is some custom scripts that run `bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/core/user_ops:all` and copy `.so` files from `bazel-bin` directory to the Download directory, and then we tell users to copy those ".so" files into "."

Answer (score 1):

You can preserve directory structure of your project and create setup.py such that it also include .so files. You can also add other non-python files of your project same way.
Example Directory Structure:

`my_package
   my_project
   __init__.py
   setup.py`

You can install 'my_project' package while in my_package directory using command:
`pip install . --user`  (Avoid --user argument if you install packages with root access)

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='my_project',
      version='1.0',
      description='Project Details',
      packages=find_packages(),
      include_package_data=True,
      package_data = {
           '': ['*.so', '*.txt', '*.csv'],
      },
      zip_safe=False)
```

Don't forget to add `__init__.py` in all folders containing python modules you want to import.
Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data